# How to Call multiple Functions inside a Render in React/Jsx

Tags: reactjs

*I am trying to return multiple functions inside render, but its not getting call from another component:---*

```
class OptionPanel extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.onRemove = this.onRemove.bind(this);
    this.onArrowUp = this.onArrowUp.bind(this);
    this.onArrowDown = this.onArrowDown.bind(this);                
}

onRemove(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.dispatch.deleteElement(this.props.DesignPanel.selectedElemId);
    {/*event.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.remove();*/}
} 

onArrowUp(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.dispatch.moveElementUp(this.props.DesignPanel.selectedElemId);
}

render(){
   return( 
       <div>
       {this.onRemove()}
       {this.onArrowUp()}
       </div>
   )
} }
```

Would this be the correct way of calling a function inside a render method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to extend `React.Component` if you only want to export functions from it

You can create a separate file `action.js`

and have

```
export function onRemove(event, dispatch, DesignPanel){
    event.preventDefault();
    dispatch.deleteElement(DesignPanel.selectedElemId);

} 

export function onArrowUp(event, dispatch, DesignPanel){
    event.preventDefault();
    dispatch.moveElementUp(DesignPanel.selectedElemId);
}
```

and then import it in the component from where you need to call them like

```
 import {onArrowUp, onRemove} from './path/to/action.js'
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing in your code-snipped is, that you're directly calling the methods (onRemove() and onArrowUp(). They will be called and whatever they return will be rendered as well.

So:

> Would this be the correct way of calling a function inside a render method?

Yes, this is the right way, however it only makes sense, if these functions will return any content, that should be rendered (like additional components).

If you want to bind these functions to certain events, you have to put the functions as attributes to components.

For a button it would be:

```
<button type="button" onClick={this.onClickHandle()}>Click me</button>
```

So whenever the button will be clicked, the method "onClickHandle" will be called.

Answer (score 0):

You miss binding the event handlers to html tags events

f.e

If you want to bind it to onClick and keyUp events

```
render(){
   return( 
       <div>
       <button onClick="{this.onRemove()}">
       <input keyUp="{this.onArrowUp()}">
       </div>
   )
} 
}
```